# WCF proxy with non-routable clients

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

This is one of those questions that unfortunately I know what I want to do, but am having problems with how to word it.  Any examples or references on how I can accomplish would be great.

What I have is a WCF endpoint that is internet facing that is currently serving a handful of methods.

What I am looking to do is have a single client be the "master node" in a network environment where additional clients will pass all WCF traffic through this host, where the master must also be able to communicate to the endpoint.  The clients do not have routable IP's which is why this scenario is needed.

The two concepts I am researching are using TCP forwarder, and also RoutingService.  All requests are client-side generated, for example:

```
bool ValidateSite(Guid SiteGuid);
bool UploadForm(string[] FormData);
```

The most basic thought I have is having the master create a proxy/tcp forwarder port, then have it, and the rest of the clients communicate through the specified port.

Is this as simple as create a helper forwarder on the master machine and point all endpoints to the defined port?

Comment: I did see a response but it's now gone.  Thanks to whoever it was that recommended RouterService.  I was able to accomplish what I was looking for by digging through: [Configuring WCF Routing Without Code](https://goo.gl/Ej5K5L) and [How to Redirect WCF SOAP Services using WCF Routing Service](https://goo.gl/Ej5K5L) for anyone else who might be stuck on this.